# InvalidOperationException: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using Google Youtube Api to authenticate my application using service account

my Json looks like

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "uityityiuy",
  "private_key_id": "hjklhkkkkkkkkkkh",
  "private_key": "sdfggfdsgsdf",
  "client_email": "asdfas",
  "client_id": "asdfasasd",
  "auth_uri": "qrwqerweq",
  "token_uri": "qrwerq",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "eryter",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "ertyertytter"
}
```

Authentication script

```
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;

 UserCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(keyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        scopes,
                        "user", 
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("somename"));

                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new 
                            BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "sosadfas"
                    });

                    return youtubeService;
                }
```

I get

> InvalidOperationException: At least one client secrets (Installed or
>   Web) should be set
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleClientSecrets.get_Secrets() in
>   GoogleClientSecrets.cs, line 45

Any One With Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After going through google developer site they say

[Service Accounts do not work with the YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service-accounts-do-not-work-with-the-youtube-api)